# Combinatorial meaning of a reduced fraction in a simple probability problem?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

A routine exercise for undergraduates says: **Given** that the number of successes in $20$ independent Bernoulli trials was $8,$ what is the **conditional** probability that exactly $3$ of those $8$ successes were in the first $10$ trials?

The answer (which actually does not depend on the probability of success on each trial, that information having been superseded by the event that there were $8$ among $20$) comes to
$$
\frac{\binom{10}3 \binom{10}5}{\binom{20}8} \approx 0.240057156
$$
A fact treated as something of no interest in such exercises is this:
\begin{align}
& \frac{\binom{10}3 \binom{10}5}{\binom{20}8} = \frac{30\,240}{125\,970} = \frac{30\times1008}{30\times4199} \\[8pt] = {} & \frac{30\times(2^4\times3^2\times7)}{30\times(13\times17\times19)} \approx 0.240057156 \tag1
\end{align}

**My question is** whether the integers in the line $(1)$ above, and in particular those within the parentheses, have some interesting combinatorial significance?

Answer (score 1):

It is more or less equivalent to ask about the $p$-adic valuation of the answer, for all primes $p$.  Here is is a standard fact that
$$ v_p(n!) = \sum_{k>0} \lfloor n/p^k\rfloor = (n-\alpha_p(n))/(p-1), $$
where $\alpha_p(n)$ is the sum of the base $p$ digits of $n$.  This means that
$$ v_p\binom{i+j}{i} = \frac{\alpha_p(i)+\alpha_p(j)-\alpha_p(i+j)}{p-1}, $$
which is a measure of how much carrying takes place when we add $i$ and $j$ in base $p$.  There are various applications of this kind of thing in algebraic topology, via the structure theory of modules over the Steenrod algebra.

Comment: As far as I recall at the moment, the only occasion I've had to think about the sum of base-something digits of an integer (when it wasn't some silly puzzle) is in the fact that the sum of the base-10 digits of an integer is congruent modulo 3 to the integer itself, and similarly with 9 instead of 3. Since 10 is not prime, some things may be different. Your statement implies that the sum of the base-$p$ digits of $n$ is congruent to $n$ modulo $p-1.$ Maybe everyone knows that except me. My unawareness of the _first_ equality in your answer is explained by the fact that I've$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$never studied $p$-adic numbers. Right now I'm wondering how much of your answer survives if you omit the mentions of $v_p$ and keep everything you've said about $\alpha_p. \qquad$